# Open and Closed Set Question

Tags: calculus

If we take an open set $S$, a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$, can we say that S is relatively open? If it closed can we say that it is relatively closed? Is this a good approach in trying to to prove that if $S$ is a clopen subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$, then it must be empty or $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: Do you mean relatively open as in [Relative Topology](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeTopology.html)? But then is it relative to what? If it is relative to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then it is the same as "normal" open.

Comment: Yes, I am saying that if S is open in R^n, then can I say it is relatively open relative to R^n

Comment: That does not mean anything significant. That's equivalent to saying if $S$ is open (closed), then $S$ is open (closed).

Comment: Yeah you're right just realized this now. Can i prove it by contradiction using the definition of open and closed sets? I don't think I can make too much progress otherwise. I was thinking I could show that if S is not empty or R^n, then the definition of open and closed sets conflict.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the definition of open and closed sets?" Also, what are you supposing to contradict? That there exists a nonempty clopen set that isn't the whole space? I'm sure there are a multitude of ways to approach this problem, given the many equivalent notions of connectedness, but I suggest you review my answer below to get a handle for things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by the sets being relatively open/closed. You need to talk about their (relative) openness/closedness w.r.t. something.

What you are describing, however, is [connectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space). I think the usual way to prove connectedness in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is to [prove it for $\mathbb{R}$](http://planetmath.org/IntervalsAreConnected) and then prove that the product of connected spaces is connected.

Comment: I am not trying to prove connectedness in this problem. I have to show that if S isnt empty or R^n, then it cannot be both open and closed.

Comment: This is equivalent to connectedness. See definitions 1 and 4 at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Topological_Connectedness. If you prove connectedness, you prove what you are looking for.